# Will deleting the .minecraft folder and restarting the game affect stuff on multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So basically I'm glitching really badly right now on this factions server.  I have no clue what to do apart from just deleting the .minecraft folder and seeing if that works.  But will that make me lose all my stuff on the server?

Comment: what type of glitching are you getting?
are you falling through the world? are you teleporting back whilst running? can you not open chests or crafting tables?

Answer (score 7):

Deleting the `.minecraft` folder will delete your single-player worlds, resource packs, mods etc.

Deleting this folder will **NOT** delete anything you have on the server, since the server files are not located in your `.minecraft` folder, they will be located at where the server is being hosted.

I am assuming this server isn't a local LAN server that you are hosting, where deleting the `.minecraft` folder could delete your world.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! If you delete `.minecraft` you will **NOT** lose the stuff on the factions server (trust me) (it is the server owners that have all your info) (not your computer) **BUT** when you delete it, don't delete your `saves folder` and `servers.dat` (this just tells Minecraft what servers your have in the multiplayer list) Once you do this, re download Minecraft! It should all be fixed! IF NOT contact the server owers